# Direct arrow with tikz-cd arrow style has extra arrowhead

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I want to draw an arrow in a regular `tikzpicture` that is styled like the arrows in `tikz-cd` diagrams. Section 3.3 of the `tikz-cd` manual gives some examples that involve nodes with labels, but I only want the arrow between two coordinates.

When I try

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram]
\path[commutative diagrams/every arrow] (-1em, 0) edge (1em, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the arrow has an extra arrowhead (pointing up) at the beginning of the arrow. How do I get rid of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `tikz-cd` arrow must be an arrow between *nodes*, but the nodes may have empty labels:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram]
\node (from) at (-1em, 0) {};
\node (to)   at ( 1em, 0) {};
\path[commutative diagrams/every arrow] (from) edge (to);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, you're explanation is not totally true; this works as expected `\begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram]
\path[commutative diagrams/every arrow] (-1em, 0) to (1em, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}`. `edge` is the culprit here; for me, `edge` is a "wild beast" that I try to avoid as much as possible.
`edge` is a beast

Comment: Though `\path[->] (-1em, 0) edge (1em, 0);` (without any `tikz-cd`) does produce a single arrowhead. Can you elaborate on why `edge` is a “wild beast”?

Comment: Perhaps it's just me who doesn't understand the proper use of `edge`, but over the time I've found and seen  some examples of odd "features" produced by using it, so I tend to avoid it.